# How can i just print one line in the file

Tags: python

```
# ***Main.py***
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
from datetime import datetime

path = 'MainImages' // containes simple images
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)

for cl in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])

def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []
    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)

    return encodeList

def markAttendance(name):
    with open('Attendance.csv','r+') as f:
        myDataList = f.readlines()
        nameList = []
        for line in myDataList:
            entry = line.split(',')
            nameList.append(entry[0])
            if name not in nameList:
                now = datetime.now()
                dtString = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                f.writelines(f'\n{name},{dtString}')

encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print('Encoding Complete')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, facesCurFrame)

    for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
        faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)

        if matches[matchIndex]:
            name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1*4, x2*4, y2*4, x1*4
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2-35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, name, (x1+6, y2-6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            markAttendance(name)

    cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Please can someone figure out when i show a face in the face cam it is writting the ttendance in Attendance.csv but it is writing the same line multiple times when i show in the camera. Please can someone fix this issue I am trying but it is not working. I am a beginner pls help.

I tried hard but it not working. I was expecting it to work after many times.

Comment: `f.writelines(f'\n{name},{dtString}')` This code is inside a loop, so of course many lines will be written.  `name` is an argument to the function and it never changes, so its value will always be the same, and `dtString` is based on the current hour-minute-second, which will probably also be the same for all the lines because the loop will run quickly.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: maybe you should create  `set()` to remember already written lines and write line when it is not in `set()` (and later add line to this `set()` to skip it in next write).

Comment: in `markAttendance` you run `if` inside `for`-loop but you should first run `for`-loop to read all data from file, and later use `if`

Comment: What's if you move `f.writelines(f'\n{name},{dtString}')` outside of `if/else` block?

Answer (score -1):

I can't run code but I think you have wrong indentations `markAttendance`,

You use `if` inside `for`-loop and it may write new line in every loop.

You should first run all `for`-loop to get all data, and later run `if` to check name.

```
def markAttendance(name):

    with open('Attendance.csv', 'r+') as f:

        # --- loop ---

        nameList = []

        for line in f:
            entry = line.split(',')
            nameList.append(entry[0])

        # --- after loop --- 

        if name not in nameList:
            dt = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            f.writelines(f'\n{name},{dt}')
```

Frankly, if you run long time then you could keep `nameList` in memory instead of reading it again and again. And later only write new name in file, and add this name directly to `nameList`.

```
def readNames():

    with open('Attendance.csv', 'r') as f:

        nameList = []

        for line in f:
            entry = line.split(',')
            nameList.append(entry[0])

    return nameList

# --- 

def markAttendance(name, nameList):

    if name not in nameList:

        nameList.append(name)   # add directly to list

        # write to file
        with open('Attendance.csv', 'a') as f:
            dt = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            f.writelines(f'\n{name},{dt}')

# --- 

nameList = readNames()   # read only once at start

while True:

        # ... 

        if matches[matchIndex]:
      
            # ...

            markAttendance(name, nameList)
```